# org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, path, oozie-workflow

I cannot access the `lexique.json` file from a Java code snippet run from an `oozie` workflow. I keep getting the following error:

```
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/user/aabbx09/lexique.json (No such file or directory)

public class ReadLexique {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException  { 
               String path = "hdfs:///bigopeclu/user/use_id/lex.json" ; 

           System.out.println("File's name: " + path)  ; 


           int size_lex = 2 ; 

           File lexiqueFile = new File(path) ; 


           Scanner lexiqueScanner = new Scanner(lexiqueFile) ;

           System.out.println("Scanner object created")  ; 
}
}
```

Any clues about what's the issue with the file path, please?

Comment: the error pretty much states it, there is no such file under `/user/aabbx09/lexique.json`
you sure you don't have to use the absolute path? please add some code you already got

Comment: Here is the code I am using and yes this is the absolute path: